# How to find alphanumeric word from a string using regular expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

> Get 20% Off Your Entire Order & FREE Shipping (first time customers only)! Enter coupon code NEW20VISION at checkout. Limited time offer.

I am getting this type of string from db.I have to find out if there is any alphanumeric word in the string.If it contains any alphanumeric word.I have underline it.Like in the above case it is:NEW20VISION

Comment: Regex matching a word with at least 1 number in it is basically 3 patterns... starts with number followed by letters or number... starts with a letters or numbers and is followed by a number then more letters or numbers... and finally letters or numbers that ends in a number.  Try writing that as a regex capture and see how it goes.  But yes I agree with Raph "what have you tried?"

Comment: ok,But I also tried  @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" but of no results

Comment: Did you try my regex with passive group?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Regex 
    /[a-zA-Z0-9]/

Or check the link : http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet5818.htm

Comment: This does not check whether at least one letter and one digit are part of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Raphaël Althaus is right, but I think it's better to add few passive groups for it to avoid getting useless matches

String for testing:

```
Get 20% Off Your Entire Order & FREE Shipping (first55 time55 custo55mers only)! Enter coudf45pon code NEW20VISION at checkout. Limited time offer.
```

Raphaël Althaus's regex:

```
\b[a-zA-Z\d]*(([a-zA-Z]+\d+)|(\d+[a-zA-Z+]))[a-zA-Z\d]*\b
```

My regex:

```
\b[a-zA-Z\d]*(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]+\d+)|(?:\d+[a-zA-Z+]))[a-zA-Z\d]*\b
```

Raphaël Althaus's regex result:

```
 ===next match===
Group[0]: first55
Group[1]: t55
Group[2]: t55
Group[3]: 
===next match===
Group[0]: time55
Group[1]: e55
Group[2]: e55
Group[3]: 
===next match===
Group[0]: custo55mers
Group[1]: 5m
Group[2]: 
Group[3]: 5m
===next match===
Group[0]: coudf45pon
Group[1]: 5p
Group[2]: 
Group[3]: 5p
===next match===
Group[0]: NEW20VISION
Group[1]: 0V
Group[2]: 
Group[3]: 0V
```

Results of my regex:

```
 ===next match===
    Group[0]: first55
    ===next match===
    Group[0]: time55
    ===next match===
    Group[0]: custo55mers
    ===next match===
    Group[0]: coudf45pon
    ===next match===
    Group[0]: NEW20VISION
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a little confusion, I think, because you search alphaANDnumeric words ( "20", "20ab", "test" are considered as alphanumerics).

this one should work (could be simplified, I'm quite sure...)

Tested with a Regex.Replace, and NEW20VISION is out of your string.

```
 var regex = @"\b[a-zA-Z\d]*(([a-zA-Z]+\d+)|(\d+[a-zA-Z+]))[a-zA-Z\d]*\b";
 var text = "Get 20% Off Your Entire Order & FREE Shipping (first time customers only)! Enter coupon code NEW20VISION at checkout. Limited time offer.";

 var text2 = "20 test 1020test test2010, test10 20";


 var t2 = Regex.Replace(text, regex, string.Empty); 
 var t3 = Regex.Replace(text2, regex, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\w*(?:\d\p{L}|\p{L}\d)\w*");
```

This matches an alphanumeric word that contains at least one digit followed by a letter or vice versa.

The only "wart" is that `\w` also matches the underscore. If you don't want that, it gets slighty more ugly:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"[\d\p{L}]*(?:\d\p{L}|\p{L}\d)[\d\p{L}]*");
```